# Need to find a value to satisfy a given geometric series equation but it seems there is no solution, is there one?

Tags: sequences-and-series, problem-solving

The geometric series given is this:

$$\sum_\limits{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(1+c)^n} = -2$$

I must find c to make the equation true. I used $a\over (1-r)$, substituting:

${(1+c)^{-1} \over 1 - (1+c)^{-1}} = -2$ and arrive at $c= -1/2$. This value however makes the series diverge as $r$ is not between $-1$ and $1$.

Please be so kind as to verify that there is no solution, or point me in the right direction or give the solution. Thank you very much!

Comment: This is hard to follow.  What sum exactly is $-2$?

Comment: The sum of $(1+c)^{-n}$ if n is taken from 1 to infinity. Just a geometric sequence with an unknown c and a known sum but it seems like this sum of -2 has no solutions for c.

Comment: It seems you solved the final equation correct, then yes, the initial equation has no solution

Comment: There is no solution to $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} r^n=-2$ for $-1<r<1$.   Indeed, the only solution to $\frac 1{1-r}=-2$ is $\frac 32$ which is not in the interval of convergence.

Comment: @lulu $n$ starts at $1$ here, in a case like this it matters.

Comment: So... no solution, right? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @ArnaudMortier  Yes, you are correct, though the conclusion is the same.  $\frac r{1-r}=-2\implies r=2$ which is, again, outside the interval of convergence.

Answer (score 1):

The series cannot converge to $-2$ so $c$ has no solution.